# Have I calculated this probability correct?

Tags: probability, statistics

I have a small question about Roulette. I have found out the probability of how many different numbers will be spun in $37$ spins.

- The possibility in $37$ spins to be spun $24$ different numbers is: $20$%
- The possibility in $37$ spins to be spun $25$ different numbers is: $16$%
- The possibility in $37$ spins to be spun $26$ different numbers is: $9$%
- The possibility in $37$ spins to be spun $27$ different numbers is: $4$%

So my question is: If there are already $34$ spins done ($3$ left out of $37$) and there are so far  $24$ different numbers spun, what is the probability that in the next $3$ spins there will be a new different number? (thus ending up with $25$ or $26$ or $27$ different numbers)

What I have thought as solution is adding up all the wanted outcomes and dividing with all possible outcomes. So:

$$\frac{25 \text{ different} + 26 \text{ different}+ 27 \text{ different}}{24 \text{ different}+ 25 \text{ different}+ 26 \text{ different}+ 27 \text{ different}}$$

So. Adding up the probabilities will be: $$\frac{16+9+4}{20+16+9+4} = \frac{29}{49} = 0.59183$$

So there is a $59,1\%$ chance that in the next $3$ spins will be a new different number and $40,9\%$ that will not be a new one (being a repeater of any previous $24$ ones)

Have I calculated it correctly or am I missed something? Would the probability be different because I made the mistake calculating based on the $37$ spins but now are $3$ spins left or is it correct?

I really appreciate any answer and help. Thank you!

Comment: The problem is that, in your expression, you are counting cases that are known to not happen. For example, there are a lot of results of $24$ that do not occur by getting $24$ in the first $34$ spins. Conditional probability is more complicated than this.

Comment: so... this  kind of calculating (my attempt) is off? is there any way i could calculate it or is it too complicated? :/ i thought by having found the chances and adding the probabilities of all scenarios could do

Comment: Sure, the answer below is a fine way to compute this.

Comment: i have not that experience as you commenting and answering so i am not trying to conviece you but to be honest i think this probability (72%) and the one in my comment in the answer (15%) is too high. Sure it suits me and i am happier to have that high probability but i think it's too good to be true. thanks for the interest though. so all the probabilities i wrote about the 37 spins(20%-16%-9%-4%)don't actually are needed for the answer? thanks for helping

Comment: If it "suits you," then you are not doing mathematics, you are gambling badly.  The answer below is accurate, your answer is wrong.  But good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculate the compliment, the probability that no new numbers occur within the next three spins:
$$1-P=\left(\frac{24}{37}\right)^3\approx0.2729$$
This gives us the probability of spinning at least one new number:
$$P=1-\left(\frac{24}{37}\right)^3\approx0.7271$$

Comment: Are you sure about that?
if that is correct then if i had 34 different numbers in 35 spins then the probability in the next 2 spins to have one more would have been P=1-(34/37)^2 = 0.1555 or 15,5% which i think it's too high.
My way on the same scenario brings result of 0,0001 or 0,01% which is i think more logical since it is VERY RARE to see 35+ different numbers in 37 spins (actually it's less than 0,000001%)

Comment: @Friday13 As Thomas Andrews pointed out in his comment, conditional probability is more complicated. Asking about the probability that $35+$ different numbers come up in $37$ spins is a rather different question from asking about the probability of getting at least one of the remaining numbers in two spins *given that* you’ve already gotten $34$ different numbers in $35$ spins. In the latter case, you’re limiting the total number of possible outcomes by requiring that $34$ of the $35$ numbers come up in the first $35$ spins.

Comment: @Friday13 Oh, and both of those questions are different from asking about the probability of getting 34 different numbers in 35 spins *and then also* getting one more different number in the next two spins.

Comment: yes ok. i think i got it a bit more clear now. thanks
@amd so... if i wanted to calculate the possibility for at least 1 new unique number in a 10 spin sequence where already there are 6 unique numbers in the 7 first spins i would do:
P=1-(6/10)^3=0.784 or P=1-(6/37)^3=0.995? dividing by 10 since 10 is maximum number of possible unique numbers or dividing by 37 since 37 is all possible numbers to be spun? thanks and i won't bother you again on this topic. i promise :)

Comment: $\frac{6}{37}$ This is the probability that you get one of the $6$ numbers previously spun. Then $\left(\frac{6}{37}\right)^3$ is the probability that this occurs on each of $3$ spins. Finally $P=1-\left(\frac{6}{37}\right)^3$ is the probability that you don't get one of the previous numbers on all three spins. (That is, at least one spin is a new number.)